# Como redirecionar todas as urls de um subdomínio para uma url específica?

Tags: wordpress, htaccess

Como posso fazer isto com `.htaccess`?

Todas as páginas de `http://axi.axitech.com.br/` devem ser direcionadas para a página `http://axi.axitech.com.br/lojas-virtuais`

Comment: voccê não pode criar uma pasta chamada `lojas-virtuais` e mover o seu wordpress pra dentro dela?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente você consegue isso com o  mod_write do apache.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

Você pode escrever diretamente no .htacess ou com uma diretiva Directory na configuração do apache.

No site do Apache você vai encontrar todo tipo de configuração possível. 
Um deles é com o RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule Pattern Substitution
```

o pattern é expressão regular mesmo.

Com rewrite rule...

No seu exemplo...

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) lojas-virtuais$1
```